# Jquery, prevent redirecting, validating then submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I need to validate a form and display the errors if there are. (that part of the script is working)

If there is no error i would like to submit the form (no ajax, just keep redirecting as before with the Posted data).

My actual code does not redirect at all. i don't see any other way than using .submit() for posting the data.

if i'm not mistaken window.location.href would not post the data.

```
 $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var count_error = 0;

    // Validating ...

    if(count_error == 0){
        $('#contact-form').submit(); //Redirecting to the form action with posted data
    }

});
```

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();`from the beginning. Then change your `if` statement to `if(count_error !== 0){ e.preventDefault(); //display errors }` Basically instead of stoping the submission of the form and then restarting it if there are no errors. Only stop it if there are errors.

Comment: Thank you, that one worked perfectly. Pretty logic indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    var count_error = 0;

    // Validating ...

    if (count_error == 0) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: you get an upvote without explaining your answer..just not right.

Comment: thank you, i instead use the solution gave by Adam Merrifield.

if(count_error !== 0){ e.preventDefault(); //display errors }

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by Adam Merrifield

> remove e.preventDefault();from the beginning. Then change your if statement to if(count_error !== 0){ e.preventDefault(); //display errors } Basically instead of stoping the submission of the form and then restarting it if there are no errors. Only stop it if there are errors. –